# Send image issue

Tags: android, sockets

I want to send bitmap to SocketServer but when i click button my app crash.

Here is part of code when i am trying to send bitmap.

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
 {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {

        MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask("192.168.1.4", 8080);

                 myClientTask.execute();
    }

 });
```

}
public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask {

```
  String dstAddress="192.168.1.4";
  int dstPort=8080;
  String response = "";

    Bitmap bm=image.getDrawingCache();



  MyClientTask(String addr, int port){
   dstAddress = addr;
   dstPort = port;
  }

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

       Socket socket = null;


       try {
        socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = 
                      new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20,
                            stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        os.write(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
        os.flush();




        int bytesRead;
        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

        /*
         * notice:
         * inputStream.read() will block if no data return
         */
                 while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                     byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                     response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                 }

       } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
       }finally{
        if(socket != null){
         try {
          socket.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
        }
       }
       return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
      {
       super.onPostExecute(result);
      }
}
```

Thats what i get in LogCat and i dont rly udnerstand that.

03-11 22:14:10.580: E/AndroidRuntime(15582): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 03-11 22:14:10.580: E/AndroidRuntime(15582): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() 03-11 22:14:10.580: E/AndroidRuntime(15582): at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200) 03-11 22:14:10.580: E/AndroidRuntime(15582): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274) 03-11 22:14:10.580: E/AndroidRuntime(15582): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125) 03-11 22:14:10.580: E/AndroidRuntime(15582): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308) 03-11 22:14:10.580: E/AndroidRuntime(15582): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) 03-11 22:14:10.580: E/AndroidRuntime(15582): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088) 03-11 22:14:10.580: E/AndroidRuntime(15582): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581) 03-11 22:14:10.580: E/AndroidRuntime(15582): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019) 03-11 22:14:10.580: E/AndroidRuntime(15582): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 03-11 22:14:10.580: E/AndroidRuntime(15582): at com.example.oac.MainActivity$MyClientTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:96) 03-11 22:14:10.580: E/AndroidRuntime(15582): at com.example.oac.MainActivity$MyClientTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1) 03-11 22:14:10.580: E/AndroidRuntime(15582): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185) 03-11 22:14:10.580: E/AndroidRuntime(15582): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)

Comment: There is  a null pointer exception on Line no 96 in your MainActivity. Could you please highlight/point out which is your line 96 in code.

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();